# printindex and tikzexternalize won't create a pdf-file for the tikz-image

Tags: indexing, tikz-external, imakeidx, externalize

When using `\printindex` and `\tikzexternalize` together, then `\tikzsetnextfilename{pdfname}` will not create a external pdf-file for the tikz-image.

See sharelatex link: [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57ea73393aa94b2d4da09f66) or code here:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3]
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{testPdfFile}
A\index{Test} simple tikz-image is here: \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `externalize` library redefines `\makeindex` and related commands in a way that's incompatible with `imakeidx`.

You can fix the wrong definitions by changing them (to be no-op, of course) in the external LaTeX run.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzifexternalizing{%
  \renewcommand\index[2][]{}%
  \renewcommand\printindex{}%
  \renewcommand\makeindex[1][]{}%
  }{}

\makeindex[columns=3]

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{testPdfFile}
A\index{Test} simple tikz-image is here: \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now.
Why does `externalize` redefine `makeindex`? Can't see to logic behind that :-) Is makeindex written with the use of tikz?

Comment: @TobiasDK They don't want to make an index during the external run, do they?

Comment: Of course not. So shouldn't they include your addition in their package, so no one else get the same issues like me?

Comment: @TobiasDK I think you can file a feature request

Comment: @egreg No need to change `\makeindex` and related commands: it is enough to load `\makeindex` before `\tikzexternalize`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé that is the bes tanswer, thanks!